# SHOW TABLES absurdly slow in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For some reason, extremely simple queries, such as `SHOW TABLES`,  can take a long time on my local machine.

```
# line from log/development.log 
SQL (955.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
```

If I execute the same query in dbconsole manually, it runs in < 0.01s

Looking through the logs for any long running queries, aside from migrations, they're all SHOW TABLES.

```
  SQL (170.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (165.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (166.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (176.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (166.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (273.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (165.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (145.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (142.8ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (165.8ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (165.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (166.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (199.2ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (155.0ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (143.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (143.4ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (153.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (354.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (210.3ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1060.0ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (854.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (254.4ms)  SHOW TABLES
```

Running Mac OS X with `Server version: 5.1.46 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Had this problem on Rails 2 and Rails 3.

Comment: Are there any particularly large tables tables in there? Are you happy with the indexes on those?

Comment: No large tables, everything is indexed. If that was the problem, I don't see why it would run a thousand times faster when done directly through the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to the new mysql2 gem. This might solve the problem.

/Carsten

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'caching' the columns:

In initializers/some_file.rb do this:

```
User.columns
OtherModel.columns
and so on...
```

This will be executed when you fire the server up, so the first time you execute a query it won't be delayed by the SHOW TABLES query.

This isn't a solution, of course, there must be something wrong with your tables, besides, I don't use this in production, I use this trick when I'm debugging something in the console to avoid Rails to show all the SHOW TABLES queries.